# jQuery load() wont reload the div and deletes all its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a JS function that is supposed to reload the content of the sidebar WooCommerce shopping cart every time the customer clicks the "add to cart" button. I have tried using the following code to reload the div the cart is located in, but it only deletes the content of the div. Thank you in advance for any help

```js
function reloadCart(){

  jQuery('#sidebar-right ').load("wp-content/themes/page/header.php #sidebar-right > *");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

1) Is your theme called Page?

2) I would check the response to the message that `.load(` sends. To do this, open the page in Google Chrome, press `ctrl+shift+i` to open developer tools. Click on your `add to cart` button. Click on the `network` tab in developer tools and check the last message  of type `xhr`. First check the Status Code in the `Headers` tab and then check it's `Response` tab to see what the server has sent back.

**XHR**

[image: xhr]

**Headers**

[image: Headers]
**Response**

[image: Response]